# Why didn't the cops investigate Richie Whelan's murder?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-drop

In the movie [The Drop](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1600196/), we see how Bob Saginowski (Tom Hardy) who acted as the bartender for Cousin Marv (James Gandolfini):

In the case of the kid that got the money from the loan shark that is cousin Marv and then paid him back, apparently Cousin Marv didn't appreciate that, and got him killed. However the cops were unable to relate Bob to the murder. And everybody around town were suspecting the bit of lunatic Eric Deeds of the act. However, it is revealed that Eric couldn't possibly be part of the murder since that day he was at a mental institute. Which leads to my question:

WHY didn't the cops act on a 10 year old murder with clear evidence that the main suspect is not guilty and the real killer is still on the loose? Am I missing something here? Couldn't they trace back the loan he got from Cousin Marv?

Comment: The detective in the movie always suspected that Bob has something to do with murders, that's why in the end he says, "No one ever sees you coming, do they Bob?". But the reason cops couldn't approach Bob is because of the lack of evidence.

Comment: @chaitanya89 To put things into perspective, the thing happened many years ago, why was the police so late to pick up the trail ? I do have a strong feeling they were kinda protected for some reason.

Comment: Just a note: we allow spoilers everywhere except the title (see [help/on-topic]). There is no need to spoiler-mark the question or answer.

Comment: Roger that @CGCampbell

Comment: I just finished reading the book and at the end nadia and bob took the dog for a walk in the park..nothing else..so it was a happy ending after all I think..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both Marv and Eric are now dead. So the cops don't actually know anything new based on that (aside from the one cop that knew Bob was the guilty one all along). So I'd say there's no new 'clear evidence' to act upon. As to why they didn't investigate earlier, I believe the issue was that the hospitalization alibi wasn't shared information between the policing departments. This seems common both in movies and real life where even though departments are seemingly on the 'same side of the law' there is internal competition and conflict between them preventing open sharing of data.

Comment: Yeah, but for many years they weren't, if they do not have a suspect, why didn't they investigate everybody around ??

Comment: @yondaime008 ah! Yes, good point. Hmm...I know it had something to do with 'left hand not talking to the right hand'. Remember that that information was only found out through the 'unofficial' sharing of information between departments during the film, so the mental institution wasn't even known by the investigators until just recently.

Comment: That's what I mean, it was shady. Why did they hide information? Couldn't cops investigate seperately the past of Eric Deeds? It is just weird. I'll try to rewatch the scene and try to find something I may have missed

Comment: @yondaime008 well, I don't know if they were 'hiding' information. I just don't think the two agencies were big on sharing in the first place. They each have different priorities and aren't necessarily worried about the other's priorities.

Comment: @yondaime008 good comments. I expanded the answer in hopes of addressing them better.

Comment: Yeah absolutely, we won't be getting any better answer :)

Comment: @CGcampbell is there a reason to remove the spoiler tag? Seems that knowing this is a spoiler (I'm not familiar with the rules as to when we should vs. should not use spoiler tags)

Comment: As my comment to the OP shows, [help/on-topic] shows what we consider our rules of usage of spoilers. Basically, the question's title should contain no spoiler information, but the rest is generally accepted as open.

Comment: @CGCampbell good to know. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

Detective Torres "knowing" what he (thinks he) knows is not the same thing as having evidence. No body, no witnesses, no direct corroboration = no arrest.  Torres simply lets Bob know that he's on to him.

This is the second time I've seen people comment about the ending.  Lehane's original short story, Animal Rescue is available online.  You may wish to read it to get more insight into Bob's personality, state of mind and motivation.  That would resolve this and change POV on what happened after the fade-to-black.

You may also wish to rewind to 3 other times where Tom Hardy's face understatedly tells it all.  Notice his eyes when Torres confronts him on the docks after he's just disposed of the arm, notice his face and wording after confronting Marv and the moment of absolute decision after Eric tells him he will kill Rocco.  It's all right there in his eyes, face and posture.  After looking at those, then re-watch that final scene.  The look on his face when Nadia reappears is one of relief.  Lehane described Bob as profoundly lonely.  I took this to mean that he had self-sentenced out of guilt, but the short story shows that Bob has always been lonely and isolated.

Comment: excellent remarks, i'll be sure to check the short story, i didn't know there was an original work that it was based on it. Thanks  !

Comment: While interesting, I'm afraid the majority of this answer (basically everything but the very first paragraph) doesn't relate to the question at all and is entirely superfluous commentary about another aspect of the story.